# Exact Dihedral angle for Disdyakis Triacontahedron

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, angle

I've tried calculating the exact dihedral angle of a [Disdyakis Triacontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disdyakis_triacontahedron), with no success. I cannot seem to find it online either. What is the correct approach to trying to figure out this value?

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest finding an explicit coordinate set and doing the whole thing 'manually' - find the normals for two adjacent faces from their coordinates and find the angle between them from a dot or cross product.

Comment: On polyhedra like the Triakis Icosahedron, it is possible to select a height for the "pyramids" on the faces such that the entire solid has the same dihedral angle everywhere. Can this not be done on the Disdyakis Dodecahedron and Triacontahedron?

Comment: @Disousa: As for calculating the vertices, if $\gamma = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{5})$ denotes the golden ratio, the twelve points $(\pm\gamma, \pm1, 0)$ (all four choices of sign) and their cyclic permutation constitute vertices of a regular icosahedron. Take three vertices of one face, form their arithmetic mean, and scale to get a vector on the same sphere as the existing vertices.

Comment: (It can indeed be done - I deleted my mistaken comment about dihedral angles.)

Comment: According to Mathematica the angle is: $\pi -\arccos\left(\frac{1}{241} \left(179+24 \sqrt{5}\right)\right)$

Comment: I just tried (on a disdyakis dodecahedron for simplicity)varying the height of the pyramid and plotting the angles of both dihedral angles of said pyramids, and I realized that the angles can only be the same if the height is zero, AKA no disdyakis...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you did, but as I wrote above Mathematica gives a well defined value for the dihedral angle, which is the same for all dihedra. You can download the notebook here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisdyakisTriacontahedron.html

Answer (score 0):

I am learning MathJax yet, i could not find any tool online to convert text into MathJax as desmos.com does but that format is not supported here..

Apologies, but i will convert it to required format in some time.

---

First an expression for the dihedral angle is must for this problem.

[image]

w.r.t the above figure

Cos(Dihedral angle)  =  1 - 2*((sin(Dihedral Angle/2))^2)  = 1 - 2*((Cos pi/n)/( cos theta))^2 = 2*asin((Cos pi/n)/( cos theta))

or

sin(Dihedral Angle/2) = (cos pi/n)/(cos theta)

Its a long derivation to show this, but to cut short the steps, lets start from this

In the below figure showing a disdyakis tricontahedron, let the angle of the unitary scalen triangle which goes up in making this be as below

[image]

now there can be three dihedral angles, each calculated taking one of the vertices of this scalen triangle as point 'O' of figure 1.

cos (Dihedral angle from A) = 1 - 2((Cos pi/10)/( cos angle A/2))^2, as n = 10 around A --(i)

cos (Dihedral angle from B) = 1 - 2((Cos pi/6)/( cos angle B/2))^2, as n = 6 around B

cos (Dihedral angle from C) = 1 - 2((Cos pi/4)/( cos angle C/2))^2 as n = 4 around C

since all of the three dihehdral angles are equal, we get the folowing equation

sin(Dihedral Angle/2) = (cos pi/10)/(cos angle A/2) = (cos pi/6)/(cos angle B/2) = (cos pi/4)/(cos angle C/2)

But angle (A + B + C) = pi & we have cos pi/10 = ((5^0.5)/(2(5^0.5 - 1)) )^0.5 (=a say) & cos pi/6 = (3^0.5)/2 (=b say) & cos pi/4 = 1/(2^0.5) (=c say)

from the above equations and after following long process of simplification, we get

cos(angle A/2) = ((((b+c)^2 - a^2)(a^2 - (b-c)^2))^0.5)/(2bc) = ((33 + (125^0.5))/48)^0.5

So, from (i) --> Cos(Dihedral angle)  =  1 - 2((Cos pi/10)/( cos angle A/2))^2 = - acos((179 + (24*(5^0.5)))/241) on substitution of above values

or  Dihedral angle = pi - acos((179 + (24*(5^0.5)))/241)

Also all the angles of the scalen triangle i.e. angles "A, B & C" can be found

as angle A = 2*acos(((33 + (125^0.5))/48)^0.5) = 32.7702785 degrees

and substituting this value in above equations we get

angle B = 2*acos((241/(280 + (1280^0.5)))^0.5) = 58.2379196 degrees &

angle C = 2*acos((241/(420 + (2880^0.5)))^0.5) = 88.9918019 degrees